How do i add a wiki link to Devops using a rest API
I am trying to update Devops using make.com. In that i want to add my exisiting wiki link to a devops ticket  .
I understand i can do this by patch, can someone help me with the body of it.
Thanks
I was trying to update my Devops for a wiki page

Hi @indreshmishra, Have you got a chance to check the answer below to use Azure DevOps - Make an API call module to call REST API and add hyperlink for a work item? Hope it helps resolve the issue in this post. Thx for taking time to share the update.

Assuming you have been testing to use the Azure DevOps - Make an API call module in Make.com, we can use the request body like below to add a hyperlink for an Azure DevOps work item.
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "Hyperlink",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_wiki/wikis/$project.wiki/36/TestWikiPage",
      "attributes": {
        "comment" : "TestWiki1"
      }
    }
  }
]

Please don't forget to modify the headers as "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json".

By the way, the web UI of Azure DevOps wiki page itself has the feature to link work items.


Thanks for the information, this works for me.

if you know your wiki link, you may use this sample: Add a hyperlink
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=7.2-preview.3

[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "Hyperlink",
      "url": "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/05/12/a-new-api-for-visual-studio-online.aspx"
    }
  }
]

